Laravel Curl error: operation aborted by callback
I have a problem when uploading files. The error description is "Curl error: operation aborted by callback". I would be very grateful if you could help me solve this problem.
public function upload_store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:15360',
        ]);

        $file = $request->file('file');
        $type = $file->getClientMimeType();
        $modulName = 'uploadModul';

        $server = 'https://example.com/file/';
        $apikey = 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx';

        $data = [
            "txtModulName" => $modulName,
            "file" => new \CurlFile(
                $file,
                $type,
                basename($file)
            ),
        ];

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $server);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;',
            'ApiKey: '.$apikey.''
        ));

        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        if(curl_errno($curl)) echo 'Curl error: '.curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        print'<pre>Curl (rec): '."\n";print_r($result);print'</pre>';
    }

I have tried various methods but nothing has worked.
Any help appreciated, thank you

You need to be pass the filename to the CurlFile constructor. curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); is dangerous and stupid.

In Laravel you should add a backslash before the CurlFile, like this:
"file" => new \CurlFile(
    $file,
    $type,
    basename($file)
)

The backslash in \CurlFile indicates that CurlFile refers to the CurlFile class in the global namespace, not a local class in the current namespace. This ensures that PHP finds the class correctly and avoids any "class not found" or "undefined class" errors.
The first parameter of the CurlFile needs to be the file's path.

I have also tried adding a backslash to the CURLfile. But it still doesn't work.

And you are passing the file or the path as the first parameter, @PendokLaravel?

I've tried both, but it still doesn't work.
Can you tell me what it should be like?

For me, only the error with the backslash, and something that looks incorrect is the parameter, but without context, it's the only two options I have now and according to my experience. Could you share the complete traceback error, please?

The error message just appears like this: "Curl error: operation aborted by callback".
I've tried replacing $file with the following code, but the result is still the same.
$fileReq = $request->file('file');
$file =  $fileReq->getRealPath();
$file =  $fileReq->getClientOriginalName();
